# CSV file row name always getting repeated

Tags: r

I am writing a csv file in `R` using nested loops with `row_name=T`, the row name always get repeated

```
m=4
n=5 
for (j in 1:m) 
{ 
    for (i in 1:n) 
    {
        write.table(data, file="result.csv", append=T, row.names=T, col.names=F,sep=",") 
    } 
}
```

output=rowname=1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,... however i want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....

Comment: You are appending to the original file and each time, the `write.table` with `row.names = TRUE`, starts from 1.

Comment: is there is any way to get sequence incrementing not repeating (i know its logical one but PLZ help me )

Comment: The argument to rownames is not necessarily logical. Read the help page: Can also be "a character vector of row names to be written." You will need to keep a running tally of the last rowname and the number of rows in the current data `argument`.

Answer (score 0):

@42-'s answer in the comments is good. In case the size of the final table isn't too big, you could also try this approach -

```
m=4
n=5 
for (j in 1:m) 
{ 
  for (i in 1:n) 
  {
    data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(40),20))
    write.table(data, file="result.csv", append=T, row.names=F, col.names=F,sep=",") 
  } 
}

final.data <- read.csv("result.csv",header = F)
final.data <- data.frame(cbind(1:nrow(final.data),final.data))
write.table(final.data, file="result.csv", row.names=F, col.names=F,sep=",")
```